# Java connection fails from jar but works from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, jsoup

I have a Java multithread application that connects to the web. After I start some number of threads, if I run it from an executable jar, the application hangs. If I run it from Eclipse it works perfectly.

This is the instruction that connects to the web:

```
Jsoup.connect(url).header("Cache-Control", "no-cache").header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0").header("Connection", "keep-alive").get();
```

These are the exceptions I get when it's run from the jar:

```
Remote host closed connection during handshake
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
at borsa.fetchers.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
... 12 more
```

.

```
Software caused connection abort: socket write error
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:734)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
at borsa.fetchers.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:23)
```

.

```
Software caused connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:730)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:706)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:299)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:288)
at borsa.fetchers.FetcherThread.run(FetcherThread.java:23)
```

**Why does it happen? How to solve it? Why this different behaviour between jar and IDE?**

---

**EDIT answer to @Wojciech Piotrowiak**

Eclipse console output: https://text-share.com/view/22a1e492
Dos console output: https://text-share.com/view/a684f1bd They seem to do same things...?

Comment: Try to log details of the SSL handshake to get more information what went wrong.

Comment: Does a single thread work fine?

Comment: A single thread works fine. How do I log SSL handshake?

Comment: These exceptions are different...

Comment: You can try VM parameter: `-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`

Comment: You can try VM parameter: `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake`

Answer (score -1):

Please run both ways with: -Djavax.net.debug=all flag to get more details.
Try to compare all JVM parameters of running application between eclipse and JAR.

There might be many reasons, maybe eclipse have specific configuration that is not set when running from Jar.

Comment: Answered in question

Comment: I cannot put comment below your question so I have to do it here: I can't see any exceptions in logs that you provided. There are many possibilities that might fail: Lack of available resources in your OS to open another connection, bad configuration of timeouts. Do you have connection pool? Please double check all ssl related properties that are set in eclipse, probably they are not placed in JAR. In eclipse logs I see 'ClientHello', 'ServerHello','ServerHelloDone' steps of TLS handshake, in jar only 'ClientHello'